# In Scheme, how do I replace elements in a list with the the elements of another list?

Tags: list, scheme, switch-statement

So, the function should take 3 arguments that are all strings. The first is the original string. The 2nd is what letters in the string should be changed. The 3rd is what the letters should be changed to. For example,

```
~ (switch-up "aabcc" "abc" "def")
```

"ddeff"

I'm not even sure how to begin with this one. Any help?

Comment: The arguments are lists or strings? the question is contradictory on this point. Also, can you use advanced procedures (say, `string-ref`) or are you limited to basic ones?

Comment: im sorry. the arguments are strings. I think I'm limited to basic ones.

Comment: OK, I adapted my answer to the updated question. It's basically the same. Another option would be to first transform the strings into lists of strings, and then operate on them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like homework, so I'll give you some hints to solve the problem using the procedures available to you. Start by splitting the problem in simpler parts - first, the actual `switch-up` procedure which basically iterates over each of the characters in the input string, processing each one in turn and building a new string with the result. Hint: use `string-ref` and `substring` for retrieving the first character and the rest of characters in the string - think of it as the `car` and `cdr` for strings.

```
(define (switch-up lst letters replacements)
  (if <???>                                      ; if the string is empty
      <???>                                      ; return the empty string ""
      (string-append (replace <???> <???> <???>) ; otherwise string-append the replacement of the first character in the string
                     (switch-up <???> letters replacements)))) ; and advance the recursion over the rest of the string
```

Second, we need a `replace` procedure that, given a single character and the letters and replacements, returns the replaced string or a string with the same input character if it was not found:

```
(define (replace c ls rs)
  (let ((idx (index-of ls c)))       ; get the index of c in the `ls` string
    (if idx                          ; if the index was found
        (string (string-ref rs idx)) ; then get the corresponding value from `rs`
        (string c))))                ; otherwise, return c unchanged
```

And finally, I found useful for the previous procedure to define a helper procedure that returns the index of a character inside the `ls` string (or `#f` if the character was not found in the string), so it's easy to go and find it in the replacement string. Hint: it will be very useful to turn `str` into a list of characters, using `string->list`

```
(define (index-of str c)
  <???>) ; ToDo: return the 0-based index of c inside str
```

Don't forget to test everything:

```
(switch-up "aabcc" "abc" "def")
=> "ddeff"
```

**Alternative:** The problem might be simpler to solve if you first transform the strings into lists of characters (using `string->list`), and at the end turn them back into strings, using `list->string`.

Comment: Whats idx? Where is that defined?

Comment: In here: `(let ((idx (index-of ls c))) ` it's the index where the character was found in the second string, so it's easy to find it in the third string

Answer (score 0):

Overview: Create a mapping from old letter to new letter.  Walk the original list, replacing each old letter with a new one.  Assuming all arguments are lists (otherwise need `string->list`):

```
(define (switch-up list old new)
  (let ((old-to-new (map cons old new)))
    (let switching ((list list) (result '())
      (if (null? list)
          (reverse result)
          (switching (cdr list)
                     (cons (cond ((assoc (car list) old-to-new) => cdr)
                                 (else (car list)))
                           result))))))
```